# Parallelized estimation of glarma time series models in R with parLapply instable

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I work with glarma (generalized autoregressive moving average) time series models in R, provided by the package [glarma](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glarma/index.html). Since a lot of independent estimations are performed on similar data sets I  parallelized the procedure via [parLapply](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf).

Unluckily, this procedure is very unstable. I run it on a single system. After a while the System freezes and becomes unresponsive. I provided a miniaturized example. My questions: How do I stabilize the parallelized glarma fitting procedure for large lists?

```
library(glarma)



library(doParallel)

  # wrapper function for glarma()
  glarma_wrapper_forecast <- function(y_X){
  X_tr <- matrix(y_X[,3:ncol(y_X)],ncol=2)
  colnames(X_tr) <- c('b_0','b_1')
  # glm model (for reference)
  # gl <- glm(matrix(y_X[,c(1,2)],ncol=2)~X_tr, family = 'binomial')
  # glarma model
  tryCatch({gl <- glarma(y=matrix(y_X[,c(1,2)],ncol=2),X=X_tr, 
               phiLags = c(1,2,3,4,5), thetaLags = c(6,7,8,9), type='Bin')})
  rm(X_tr)
  gc()
  if(exists('gl'))
    return(gl)
  else
    return(NULL)
}

# setup data (y: response, X: design matrix)
n_total <- 1000
X_1 <- matrix(rep(1,n_total),nrow=n_total)
set.seed(1337)
X <- cbind(X_1,rnorm(n=n_total,mean=0,sd=3))
colnames(X) <- c('b_0','b_1')
y_1 <- ifelse(pnorm(q = rowSums(X) + rnorm(n=nrow(X),mean=0,sd=2)) > 0.5, 1, 0)
y_2 <- ifelse(y_1 == 1, 0, 1)
y <- matrix(c(y_1,y_2), nrow = n_total, byrow = F)

#  - input to list format
y_X_list <- list()
n_train <- round(0.8*n_total)
for(i in n_train:n_total){
  y_X_list[[length(y_X_list) + 1]] <- matrix(c(y[1:i,], X[1:i,]), nrow=i)
}

# setup cluster & compute parallelized
no_cores <- max(1,detectCores()-5)
cpu_cluster <- makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterEvalQ(cl=cpu_cluster, library(glarma))
clusterExport(cl=cpu_cluster, "y_X_list")
# parLapply
mu <- parLapply(cl=cpu_cluster, X=y_X_list, fun=glarma_wrapper_forecast)
stopCluster(cpu_cluster)
```

I tried to narrow done the problem:

1. Different parallelized approach: `foreach`, `clusterApply` etc. yield the same problem. Using a different package, i.e. `library(parallel)` does not solve the problem.
2. Executing the file from the command terminal instead of RStudio is not better.
3. Thread Management: I have 12 physical cores, 24 Threads (AMD Threadripper 1920X). The computation works fine for a few minutes, many of the cores running at or close to full capacity. Taking out 2 to 10 threads from the cluster does not resolve the problem.
4. Creating a cluster explicitly as 'FORK' (I run Ubuntu OS) does not help either.
5. Memory management: Not critical. RAM is in use at 20% max and it still freezes. For other applications RStudio goes to 100% RAM and even close to 100% swap without any problem. Then it provides a gentle 'fatal error' instead of freezing the system. Using `remove()` and invoking the garbage collector `gc()` on top does not help either.
6. (!) `glarma` package itself: Interestingly, fitting `glm()` instead of a `glarma()` models scales nicely. If the list becomes very large (~10000) RStudio displays a fatal error after going 100% of RAM memory usage and close to 100% swap, but it does not freeze the system as for glarma models and moderate list sizes (~500).

System information:
Threadripper 1920X, 64GiB RAM, OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, R-Version: 3.4.3 (2017-11-30), Platform: Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Details on glarma:
Time series model for count data (binary in this case) which uses an ARMA-lag structure to model serial dependence and covariates to model the conditional probability of the response variables. My simple example includes an intercept and 1 covariate vector and no serial dependence (i.e. glm fit suffices) to keep the code simple. The generation of the response variable is additionally influenced by a second normally distributed covariate, not included in the model to avoid numerical intractability. The responses y are encoded as a matrix as this is required by the `glarma` package.

Thank you very much.

Comment: So, is this a memory issue (of the results)?

Comment: It does not seem this way, at least concerning RAM: With glm instead of glarma the code runs smoothly for way longer lists. Furthermore, the system crashes with glarma when memory usage is ~20%. But if you refer to memory respect to some interne R core mambo jambo, I have no idea.